# Wrong time on Domain Controller running as guest on Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, domain-controller, time-synchronization

As stated in the headline our Domain Controller runs on Windows Server. This server is a Hyper-V Guest.
The Hyper-V Host is joined to the Domain.

Unfortunately the Time on the Domain Controller is off by a couple of minutes. As a result all clients in our Domain have a wrong Windows Time.

How can this (time-synchronization) be fixed?

Comment: Which version of Hyper-V? Did you bother setting up the external time source on the DC - as you should? So it pulls the time not from hyper-v but from the internet.

Comment: Odds are that your VM is synchronizing time with the hardware clock on the host, rather than a reliable time source (like an external NTP server).

Comment: We use Windows Server 2012. Hyper-V 6.2.9200.16384 I disabled TimeSync to the DC in Hyper-V - w32tm /query /source : time.windows.com,0x01

Answer (score 1):

The Time synchronization Integration Service should be disabled on all domain members that are virtual machines running under Hyper-V, not just the DC. Your PDCe should be configured to sync time with a reliable external time source.

On boot up, the virtual machines will get their time from the Hyper-V host (because they have no RTC of their own) and from that point forward they should be syncing their time from the domain hierarchy.

From an elevated command prompt on the domain members run `w32tm /query /source` and make sure that the source is your PDCe. Then run `w32tm /query /configuration` and make sure the type is NT5DS.

From an elevated command prompt on the PDCe run `w32tm /query /source` and make sure that the source is a reliable external time source. Then run `w32tm /query /configuration` and make sure the type is NTP.

Answer (score -1):

The standard setup is to disable the time service on the domain controller and set it up to get an external time.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784553(v=ws.10).aspx
Describes the steps. This is pretty imperative as otherwise you alck any decent time source (no, computers have lousy clocks).

If you do that properly, you break the host/client time loop and all machines should get the proper time.

Comment: I disabled TimeSync to the DC in Hyper-V  -  w32tm /query /source : time.windows.com,0x01

Comment: Did you follow the rest of the steps in the article TomTom links to? What is the result of the command `w32tm /query /status` You may also need to ensure NTP is allowed through your firewall (UDP/123)

Comment: And I think that you are not too far off (or restart the VM) - as the ONGOING synchronization has a time differential limit, IIRC. you may well see the warnings in the event log. The "initial" sync after a reboot, IIRC, has no time differential limit.